# Formatting outputs created with .join command

Tags: list, image, rgb

I am doing a project on a Raspberry Pi Pico running Micro Python to which I am new at in terms of programming having never touch Python or any variant before I started a about a month ago.

I came here as I needed something to turn a small JPG image into a text file of RGB values my project and the only way I could find to do this was some code I found here. But this mostly dos what I want but not fully

The code I found here which was:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('01.jpg')
with open('JpgtoRGBoutput.txt', 'w') as f_out: 
    for i in img: 
        f_out.write('|'.join(['{},{},{}'.format(*j) for j in i]) + '\n')
```

I've managed to adapt the code so it separates each pixel's RGB value onto a separate line by swapping the '|' part for '\n' so I get an output which reads something like:

162,53,2
231,127,80
211,116,72
157,56,11
190,67,11
191,57,0
198,61,0
195,68,0
166,58,4

but I now have 2 issues.

1. I need to add a number to identify the pixel before it's RGB value
2. I need each value to be 3 digits so instead of saying "255,25,5" I need it to say "001,255,025,005" (001 being the pixel number, the rest being the RGB value) because of how my micro python code reads the data into the Pico for use.

I tried this:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('01.jpg')
cnt = 0
with open('JpgtoRGBoutput.txt', 'w') as f_out: 
    for i in img: 
        f_out.write('\n'+str(c)+",".join(['{},{},{}'.format(*j) for j in i]) + '\n')
        cnt += 1
```

But that only adds a number to the start of each line of pixels so I can work out that "i" is a line of pixels from the image and "j" presumably is a value within the line of pixels.

I've looked up the .join command but it confuses me because I am new to all of this. Can someone point me in the direction on how to achieve what I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

As you comment, `i` is a 2-D array consisting of a row data;
then we cannot increment the pixel index number in the `i` loop.
Instead we need to explicitly decompose the array into pixel data `j`,
consisting of R, G, and B values. Would you please try:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('01.jpg')
with open('JpgtoRGBoutput.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    c = 1
    for i in img:
        for j in i:
            f_out.write('{:03d},{:03d},{:03d},{:03d}'.format(c, *j) + '\n')
            c += 1
```

The output will look like:

```
001,254,251,243
002,224,221,213
003,121,118,110
004,086,084,074
005,086,084,073
006,089,087,076
007,101,099,088
[...]
```

`{:03d}` is a format specifier corresponding to `"%03d"` in `c` or other languages.